# EPiServer MVC currentPage issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver

I'm currently having some problems with the following codesnippets which seems almost identical to me, but behaves differently.

These snippets are from two different projects I've been working on, and they are built the same way but only one of them works correctly.

These are the Forms where I enter the controllers:

Form 1, inside a twitter bootstrap dropdown menu, located in the _Layout file:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditProfile", "ProfilePage", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <li>
        <button type="submit" class="dropdownButton">Redigera Profil</button>
    </li>
    }
```

Form 2, tried different locations but right now it's in a table in a Block view:

```
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EditProfile", "ProfilePage", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <button type="submit">Redigera profil</button>
        }
    </td>
```

Both seems pretty identical, right?

Now here are the controllers

Controller 1:

```
    public ActionResult EditProfile(ProfilePage currentPage)
    {
        var model = new ProfilePageViewModel(currentPage);
        model.CurrentUser = ConnectionHelper.GetUserInformationByEmail(User.Identity.Name);
        return View("EditProfile", model);
    }
```

Controller 2:

```
    public ActionResult EditProfile(ProfilePage currentPage)
    {
        ProfilePageViewModel model = new ProfilePageViewModel(currentPage);
        model.currentUser = ConnectionHelper.GetCurrentUserByEmail(User.Identity.Name);
        return View("EditProfile", model);
    }
```

Also pretty much identical.

I've added the same routing in both projects:

```
    protected override void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        base.RegisterRoutes(routes);
        routes.MapRoute(
          "Default",                                             
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
    }
```

Now here's the problem:

Form 1 and controller 1 works perfectly and recieves the ProfilePage currentPage without any problems, but form 2 and controller 2 doesn't work and gets null value.
As I stated earlier Form 1 is posted on the _Layout page and Form 2 is posted from a Block which is rendered within an mvc @section. I don't think this is the problem because I've tried to access the controller from different parts of the page, but it's not working anywhere - but in the other project it's working everywhere, which is driving me insane.

Does anyone have any idea why it is like this? I've stepped through both of them while debugging but the only difference is that one works and the other doesn't.

Thanks in advance

deSex

**EDIT :**

Here I render a section called "content", where almost everything will be rendered.

```
    <div id="content">
     @RenderBody()
     @RenderSection("content", false)
    </div>
```

My startpage has a ContentArea for blocks, rendered within this section:

```
@model Intranet.Models.ViewModels.StartPageViewModel
@section content{
   @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
       <div class="contentArea">
           @Html.PropertyFor(x => x.MainContentArea)
       </div>
   }
}
```

And here is the controller that inherits from BlockController:

```
public class ProfileBlockController : BlockController<ProfileBlock>
{
    public override ActionResult Index(ProfileBlock currentBlock)
    {
        ProfileBlockViewModel model;
        if (currentBlock != null)
        {
            model = new ProfileBlockViewModel(currentBlock);
        }
        else
        {
            model = (ProfileBlockViewModel)Session["model"];
        }
        model.CurrentUser = ConnectionHelper.GetCurrentUserByEmail(User.Identity.Name);
        var availableStatuses = ConnectionHelper.GetAllOfficeStatuses();
        availableStatuses.Remove(model.CurrentUser.OfficeStatus);
        model.AvailableStatusChanges = availableStatuses;
        Session["model"] = model;

        return PartialView(model);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `Controller 2` ineherit from

Comment: Both inherits ProfilePageController : PageController<ProfilePage>

Comment: How is that block rendered? Normally a block would be rendered by a controller inheriting BlockController?

Answer (score 1):

The "**currentPage**" route value (i.e. parameter) will only be set by EPiServer's page route. It will always be null in a block controller.

However, you can get the page of the current request in a block controller with:

```
PageRouteHelper.Page
```

If the block is being rendered as part of a request for a profile page, you'll be able to get that profile page through **PageRouteHelper**.

Comment: I think you misunderstood: I'm submitting the form FROM the block, but I want to LAND on a ProfilePage, where the currentPage gets null in the ProfilePageController.

If I use the PageRouteHelper.Page I get the StartPage which is where the post occurred inside the ContentArea where the block is located.

Comment: The 'currentPage' action method parameter in your block controller will always be null, unless you're actually including a 'currentPage' route value manually? I'm not sure what you're expecting 'currentPage' to be in your block controller when you're POSTing from the start page?

Comment: What I'm wondering about is why the identical actionresults/controllers doesn't work.
Would you mind ellaborating how I could use PageRouteHelper? Because I only get the page I came from, not the requested page by using that code.
The BlockController has a currentBlock parameter, the PageController for ProfilePage has the currentPage parameter, which gets null when the post is recieved in the PageController, from the Block view.

Comment: When the block controller's action method handles the post, the "current page" at that point is the page where the post was made (available through PageRouteHelper). The "currentPage" parameter will only be set for controllers when a *page* is being requested, which is not the case when the block controller handles the post from your form. I think you need to revise your logic, there seems to be some MVC confusion. :)

Comment: Any tips about what I can do to solve this?
I mean I cannot post to the ProfileBlockController and try to recieve a ProfilePage and then redirect that page to the ProfilePageController, because it will turn out the same way as I have now, right?
Posting to the ProfilePageController doesn't recieve a page either, can I add a Content/PageReference node of a specified type in the form in some smooth matter?

Comment: The fact that your action method is copy-pasted in two separate controllers is a red flag. :) However,  looking at your views it seems both forms are set up to post to ProfilePageController? However, when posting you never set the "currentPage" parameter, so it will be null. The "currentPage" parameter is set for page controllers when a page is requested, which isn't the case when you simply post to the ProfilePageController.

Comment: The different controllers are in different projects, as stated above :)
The issue is that one of them is working and the other one doesn't.
I "solved" my problem by adding a tab in the CMS called Default Page Settings and multiple ContentReference properties for the default pages such as searchPage, ProfilePage etc and just pass it on to the viewmodel of the page I'm posting from, adding it as a node in the form.

Do you have any suggestions of how I can do it better?